# Decrypt my Micro SD Card

Tags: encryption, storage, samsung-galaxy-apollo

I have been looking every where for an answer to this.  I had a Razor MAX with an encrypted card in it.  Well I dropped that phone and it died on the spot.  I now have a SG3 and the micro sd card works fine but the files that were encrypted are still that way and I can't open them.  Any ideas on how to decrypt just those files??

Comment: Do you have the encryption key?

Answer (score 1):

Without the encryption key, you won't be able to decrypt the files on the SD card. Your only option, in this case, is to format the SD card and start over. The idea of encryption is that nobody can access your files without the encryption key. In the case of Android, your encryption key is NOT the password you use to unlock the device. That password is just a password of a password.